# After adding an existing module to a project, the members are not recognized

Tags: vb6

I have 2 VB6 projects.  I've added some code from project A to project B that are very similar.  I also added an existing bas module from project A to project B.  This bas module contains the functions and subroutines that are called from the migrated code.

When I try to debug the project, I get

> 'Compile error. Sub or Function not defined'

on one of the public subroutines that is in the bas module.  Also, when viewing the bas module I added to project B in the object browser, no members are shown.  When viewing the same bas module in project A's object browser, all of the members show as expected.

These are the steps I did to add the bas module to project B:

- Copy the file to the project folder.
- In the project explorer, right click and select 'Add' -> 'Module' ->
  'Existing' ->
- select the module -> 'Open'.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, there is a conditional compilation argument set in project A that was not set in project B.  Problem solved.